# Get average of rows based on their position to a column header that matches a string

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with columns that contain values of a continuous variable (evapotranspiration) for each month. The column headers for my ET data are the first day of the month (e.g., 2010-01-01, 2010-02-01, etc.). I have another column that contains the year and month of a specific event (e.g., 2010-01) for each row, where each row is a different monitoring station. I want to get the average of the 2 months of my continuous variable (evapotranspiration) that precede the month of the specific event. Example below shows 'new_var' as my desired output.

```
StationId 2000-01-01  2000-02-01  2000-03-01  2000-04-01  fire_date  new_var
1         0.1         0.2         0.3         0.4         2000-03    0.15
2         0.25        0.25        0.5         0.7         2000-04    0.375
```

Please help! I've not discovered how to index a mean() argument using the position of rows relative to a column header that contains values in a string unique to each row.

Comment: Can you share reproducible example using dput() ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get data in long format, keep only month and year information from column names. For each  `StationId` select two previous rows of month that match date in `fire_date` and take `mean` of those values. Join the data to add that as a new column in the original  data.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = matches('\\d+-\\d+-\\d+')) %>%
  mutate(name = substr(name, 1, 7)) %>%
  group_by(StationId) %>%
  slice({i <- which(fire_date == name);c(i-2, i-1)}) %>%
  summarise(new_var = mean(value)) %>%
  left_join(df, by = 'StationId')

# StationId new_var `2000-01-01` `2000-02-01` `2000-03-01` `2000-04-01` fire_date
#      <int>   <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>    
#1         1   0.15          0.1          0.2           0.3          0.4 2000-03  
#2         2   0.375         0.25         0.25          0.5          0.7 2000-04
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(StationId = 1:2, `2000-01-01` = c(0.1, 0.25), 
    `2000-02-01` = c(0.2, 0.25), `2000-03-01` = c(0.3, 0.5), 
    `2000-04-01` = c(0.4, 0.7), fire_date = c("2000-03", "2000-04"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```